# What is the significance of the term "never start changing the borders in Eastern Europe by force?"

Tags: world-war-two, world-war-one, world

I have read this was the cause of both World War 1 and World War 2. Russia has now seized the Crimea and followed that up with a War in Eastern Ukraine. What are some political theories behind such developments that may have relevance today?

Comment: Quote without context/citation; demonstrates insufficient preliminary research.  Sounds like a conspiracy theory, quote may have no significance whatsoever.

Comment: Isn't this essentially asking for an evaluation of the current political situation? In which case, it would be better suited in Politics SE.

Comment: Even World War is Politics by other Means strikes me as an odd view. Questioning "Why we Fight" strikes me as an odd form of Conspriracy as well.

Comment: It is much easier. When Ukraine agreed to stop being a nuclear power in 1992 or 3, USA and Russia guaranteed its borders and safety. And you can see how well they both keep their agreements. I think, from now on there will be no fool to stop being a nuclear power.

Answer (score 2):

This relates to the so-called [Heartland Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Geographical_Pivot_of_History) by people like Britain's HJ MacKinder. Whoever controls East Europe dominates the "Heartland" (which also includes Germany and Russia) of World Island (the Eurasian land mass). Whoever controls the Heartland dominates World Island. And whoever controls World Island dominates the world.

Therefore, any forceful change of the balance of power in East Europe will likely have global [domino effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_theory) (maybe not World War III).

Comment: I find the concept of "Western Betrayal" and World War 2 interesting...especially as it regards Finland. Great Britain declared War on Finland in World War 2 and I never understood that. Also now that we have "Space Travel" I don't really understand the whole "resource thing" anymore. The virility part seems overstated now as well too...though maybe not with the millions of refugees streaming into Western Europe currently. Thanks for the reply.